# Initializing array in assembler

Tags: arrays, assembly, fasm

I just started learning ASM, I have C experience but I guess it doesn't matter.
Anyway how can I initialize a 12 elements array of DT to 0s, and how not to initialize it?

I use FASM.

Comment: The language is called "assembly" and the piece of system software that turns it into an executable is called an "assembler".

Answer (score 1):

Since arrays are just a contiguous chunk of memory with elements one after the other, you can do something like this in NASM (not sure if FASM supports the `times` directive, but you could try):

```
my_array:
    times 12 dt 0.0
```

That is expanded out when your source is assembled to:

```
my_array:
    dt 0.0
    dt 0.0
    dt 0.0
    dt 0.0
    dt 0.0
    dt 0.0
    dt 0.0
    dt 0.0
    dt 0.0
    dt 0.0
    dt 0.0
    dt 0.0
```

Comment: I tried that and I get invalid operand when I do it with times syntax.

Comment: Oh, yeah it supports times directive but i don't know why I can't use it with dt variable x_x

Comment: You can't initialize tbytes to integers, only to floats: *times 12 dt 0.0*

Answer (score 0):

Just use the *reserve data* directive and reserve 12 tbytes:

```
array:          rt 12
```

Comment: well then I would have to reserve 10x12 bytes right? dt is 10 bytes.

Comment: And then can I normally reffer to that bytes like that  :mov eax, [array+10](second element)?

Comment: Yes, but as you are working with tbytes perhaps you meant something like fld tbyte [array+10]?

Comment: Why is that? I just started learnign some things are still blur to me.

Comment: eax is 32 bits, you can only fit four bytes there. tbytes are mostly used for 80-bit full-precision floating-point numbers.

Comment: Ahh, I see and if I want to put data to second element? mov [array+10], 2 is not working

Comment: You need to set the operand size for immediate-to-memory transfers. For 32 bit: mov dword [array+10], 2

Comment: Damn it I had it like that but I thought putting dw will be enough. Thanks